# Route wait for async data before redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I came from Angular world where resolve data for route is realy easy and out of the box. How can I do the same action in react?

Add async data loder for route so that redirect will after data is ready? I am using react-router.

I saw somewhere that I could use the `Router.run()` method to write own callback, but I can not find it in the official documentation.

**I do not want to use `componentWillMount`** because sometimes the data loads in seconds and the page flashes.

I know that the topic appears many times, but I can not find a satatory answer. I will be very graceful for help with the solution.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, waiting for data before redirecting may cause bad user experience, because the user will need to wait something and he may not understand that the application is actually doing something in background.

It is better to render the UI and then take care of delivering the actual data to the page.

I usually use **componentDidMount** for such things.

E.g.:

- Component is rendered without the data
- Data is fetched within **componentDidMount**
- The UI is then updated by setting the state

Depending on the specific look of the component, a loading icon can be shown as well.

Comment: Maybe you right, I partially agree with you. But what with waiting for data before redirect, is there any solution?

Comment: While you may think you are offering a better UX please answer the question as asked. For UX discussion please switch to https://ux.stackexchange.com